# Plotting a Log Plot in Octave

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I am making a plot and I need the y-axis to logarithmic to properly convey it.
[image: Log plot]

My code is using `semilogy(thickness, decay, "linestyle", "none", "marker", '.');` to plot the dots, the line gets added later. I then set the y axis limits by using `ylim([0.5, e^2.5])` just some values that made it look nice. It is scaled properly, but the y-axis tick marks, do not properly convey what the y values are. Is there any way I can make it more precise?

Here is my code:

```
thickness = [0.0000001, 0.3793761225,1.214276572,2.040353323,2.689048044,4.146110391,10.04557497,15.7447715,25.79869234,];
decay = [5.8784,7.146537842,6.165467626,5.636820926,5.302279485,4.375803624,2.204500978,1.337231057,0.6126601356,];
t=thickness(2:end);
d=log(decay(2:end));
p = polyfit(t,d,1);
m = p(1)
b = p(2)
gca = semilogy(thickness, decay, "linestyle", "none", "marker", '.');
hold on;
x = linspace(min(t),max(t), 100);
plot(x, e.^(m.*x+b));
title("The Radioactivity of Caesium-137");
xlabel("Thickness (mm)");
ylabel("Radioactivity Log(Becquerels)");
ylim([0.5, e^2.5])
#set(gca, 'ytick', [0,e^2]);
```

Comment: Please add some code which someone can try out. 8 code lines (with linear regression) should be feasible

Comment: @Andy, Thank you I added my code.

Comment: You shouldn't overwrite the builtin function `gca`. If you change this the `set(gca, 'ytick'...)` works as you would expect. You can also manually set the yticklabels if you want

Comment: How exactly would I do that? That seems to be the resolve to my troubles. I see some documentation on the subject, although some example of sorts would be a world of help: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Axes-Properties.html#Axes-Properties

Comment: I seem to have gotten what I want on a different graph using `set(gca, 'xtick',(0:13));`

Comment: Your earlier comment makes a lot more sense now, everything seems to have come together in my mind.